# DraggableScrollableSheet flutter resets to minSize when keyboard shows up

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

The application has a screen where I am using `DraggableScrollableSheet` for the user to pull up the card. This card has a `TextField` in the middle and whenever the user taps on it, it opens up the keyboard.
The issue I am facing is, that whenever the keyboard comes up, it causes the sheet to move to `minSize` again. It looks like a glitch in the UI.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Here's the code

```
  NotificationListener<DraggableScrollableNotification>(
      onNotification: (d) {
        extent = d.extent;
        return true;
      },
      child: DraggableScrollableSheet(
        initialChildSize: .175,
        minChildSize: .175,
        maxChildSize: heightFactorForBottomNavScreen,
        snap: true,
        snapSizes: [.175, heightFactorForBottomNavScreen],
        controller: widget.draggableScrollableController,
        expand: false,
        builder: (BuildContext context, ScrollController scrollController) {
          double extentInPercent =
              (heightFactorForBottomNavScreen - (extent)) /
                  heightFactorForBottomNavScreen;
          final ThemeData theme = Theme.of(context);
          return Theme(
            data: theme.copyWith(
                colorScheme: theme.colorScheme
                    .copyWith(secondary: Colors.transparent)),
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
              controller: scrollController,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  /// removing the swipe/tap area so that we can open the bottom page till the top
                  Container(
                    height: 170 * extentInPercent,
                    color: Colors.white38,
                    child: LayoutBuilder(builder: (_, size) {
                      double width = size.maxWidth / _noOfPages;
                      return Row(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: List.generate(_noOfPages, (index) {
                          double sIndex = widget.selectedIndex - index;
                          bool selected = sIndex.abs() <= 0.5;
                          return GestureDetector(
                            behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
                            onTap: () {},
                            child: Container(
                              color: Colors.transparent,
                              width: width,
                              height: 120,
                            ),
                          );
                        }),
                      );
                    }),
                  ),
                  NavigateHome()
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    ),
```

this `NavigateHome()` is the dialog which has a text field basically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out to be an issue with the `DraggableScrollableSheet`.
For future references [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/106777) is the link to my GitHub issue

Answer (score 3):

I think that when the keyboard appears `DraggableScrollableSheet` is rebuilt to its `initialChildSize`. Thus a solution should be to dynamically control the value of `initialChildSize`.

For exemple I have add the following code :

```
@override
void didUpdateWidget(covariant Panel oldWidget) {
  keyboardSize = MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom / MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
  super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
}
```

And then in the widget :

```
DraggableScrollableSheet(
  initialChildSize: initialSize + keyboardSize,
  ...
```

PS : You can add `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false` in your Scaffold to prevent the Scaffold from resizing when the keyboard pops up.

Comment: it working with this fix